# Eclipse not highlighting current line in remote debug mode

Tags: java, eclipse, highlight, remote-debugging

I am using Eclipse Indigo on Mac OS X Lion. When trying to remote debug a project its taking painfully long to highlight current line. Its stopping correctly at the break point and I am able to step through code and all but the current line itself is not getting highlighted. It highlights it only after around 4 to 5 minutes after which everything is OK.

I have noticed the same problem in CentOS also. Is this a bug in eclipse or am I the only facing this issue.

Comment: is the remote machine on a remote network, vpn or similar?

Comment: Its on my local machine itself.

Answer (score 10):

I had the same problem after switching a workspace.

Just restarting Eclipse solved it.

(Eclipse Mars v4.5.0)

Comment: Restarting Eclipse solved my problem too, even if I haven't switched the workspace before.

Answer (score 2):

**Just check your preferences here:**

Window > Preferences > General > Editors > All Text Editors > Annotations > 'Debug Call Stack'  and 'Debug Current Instruction Pointer'

And check for color and change it accordingly.

Comment: Its all enabled. Like I said, its highlighting the pointer but only after 4 minutes.

Comment: if its all enabled - restore default (eclipse default are quite good ) - and restart eclipse

Answer (score 2):

I had similar issue. I see it highlighted, stopped at breakpoint. But I wasn't able to use step by step (F6) debug. Reason was that eclipse stopped due to break point and highlighted/selected top thread in debug.

So I selected current thread, by verifying one by one, till the current code(stopped due to breakpoint) highlighted.

To see threads running add debug view if not shown. Window > Show view > Debug.

This also helped me while debugging 2 threads separately on running programme.

There seems no short keys to locate current Thread from code stopped due to breakpoint.